# Spring WebFlux App, endpoint return List of Mono<?>

Tags: spring-webflux

I have two methods, method A returns a Mono, Method B calls method A x number of times, and need to return all the results from calling method A

```
i tried:

`
public Mono<String> methodA() {
    return Mono.just(Math.random()+"");
}

@GetMapping("/methodB/{amount}")
public Mono<List<String>> methodB(@PathVariable("amount") int x) {
    Mono<List<String>> strs = Mono.just(new ArrayList<>());
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
       strs.zipWith(methodA())
       .map(t->{
          t.getT1().add(t.getT2());
          return t.getT1();
       }
    }
    return strs;
}
`
when i hit the endpoint with browser, all i get is
[]
```

what should methodB return? how do I combine the results of calling A so that the calling Client of /methodB will get a list of String?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you actually tried?

Comment: I edited the original post for what i have tried.

Comment: I got it working...
i needed to do
`strs = strs.zipWith(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `Mono.just` to `Mono.fromCallable` to generate new random number for each subscription. Use `Mono.repeat` to generate `x` number of random numbers.

```java
public Mono<String> methodA() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> String.valueOf(Math.random()));
}

@GetMapping("/methodB/{amount}")
public Mono<List<String>> methodB(@PathVariable("amount") int x) {
    return methodA()
        .repeat(x)
        .collectList();
}
```